# Android Wifi Status Bar Indications

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

i have some doubts regading wifi in android devices.

Some times when WIFI was connected as LIMITED, how the WIFI status bar(signal) will appear.
there are some colours like grey, yellow, green or blue...
if it was connected fully then it will show blue or green..
***i want to know which colors it will show when it was connected limitedly...***

in my android device there are only two colors 1.grey,2.blue

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you see the wifi icon in status bar, you're connected.
When it's gray, it means that you're not receiving or sending data by wifi, when it's blue, data are sent/received.

Comment: thank you ..for your explanation and i am having one more doubt....what is difference between limited connection and full connection..???
In both cases net is connecting then where the difference lies...(please tell me in developer point of view)

Answer (score 0):

This work on service and broadcast which happens when network state change then a broadcast has been invoked then service starts from there onRecieve method then with the help of wifi api android system app change its icons depend on current calculation from wifi api.